# Laravel stores temporary files instead

Tags: php, laravel

I have code below and instead of saving files it saves temporary files in location

## Code

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    //validate the file
    if (!$request->hasFile('file_to_import')) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status'  => 'fail',
            'message' => trans('json.needSelectFile'),
        ]);
    }

    $file = $request->file('file_to_import');

    if (strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension()) != 'csv') {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status'  => 'fail',
            'message' => trans('json.needValidCSV'),
        ]);
    }

    $disk = Storage::disk('local');

    if (!$disk->exists('feeds/translations')) {
        $disk->makeDirectory('feeds/translations');
    }

    $uploaded_date = now();
    $name_without_extension = str_replace('.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(), '', $file->getClientOriginalName());

    $new_filename = $name_without_extension . ' - ' . $uploaded_date . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = storage_path('app/feeds/translations/', $new_filename);
    $file->move($location);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'status'   => 'success',
        'filename' => $new_filename,
    ]);
}
```

`file i uploaded`

[image: two]

`what saved in my app location`

[image: one]

## What I need

Is to save real file `translator_translations - 2019-04-15 05:52:50.csv` and not tmp file.

**any idea?**

Comment: use put method like Storage::disk('local')->put($myfilename, $filedata);

Comment: Pretty sure the `,` should be a `.` (full stop/period) in `$location = storage_path('app/feeds/translations/', $new_filename);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass filename into the `move()` function instead of any other otherwise it will take temporary name.

```
$file->move($destinationPath,$filename);
```

> **Notes :**

You should use proper filename. Filename should not contain any special character like spaces, comma and colon (:).

Comment: it says: `Could not move the file "C:\Users\Theo\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBF29.tmp" to "C:\laragon\www\.....\storage\app/feeds/translations\Translation_Template - 15-04-2019 06_30_18 - 2019-04-15 06:29:37.csv" (move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Users\Theo\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBF29.tmp' to 'C:\laragon\www\pursury\storage\app/feeds/translations\Translation_Template - 15-04-2019 06_30_18 - 2019-04-15 06:29:37.csv')`

Comment: @mafortis Can you please use proper file name convention as per laravel? `Translation_Template - 15-04-2019 06_30_18 - 2019-04-15 06:29:37.csv` this is not proper file name. It should be `Translation_Template_15-04-2019_06_30_18_2019-04-15_06_29_37.csv`.
You need to remove `spaces`,`-`,`:` from filename please.

Comment: I changed my date part to `$uploaded_date = now()->format('Y-m-d_H_m_s');` and it's uploading now, quick question? is there anyway i get my file name as i was? because i need that name config for another function which runs after uploading file, if i can't get names like that then i have to change lots of codes again :/

Comment: You can add another field into the database like `original_name` in that you can store the original filename. Then you can use that name to compare and get the files according to the filename.

Comment: @mafortis if you satisfy with the answer and it resolved your issue as per question then please give upvote and accept it as answer please. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You Wrong Approach Use move function supply two parameters old directory to new directory You remove this line `$file->move($location);` and use `$file->storeAs(
    $location, $new_filename
);`

Comment: It says: `Impossible to create the root directory "C:\laragon\www\....\storage\/app\C:/laragon/www/.../storage/app/feeds/translations".`

Comment: $file->storeAs(
    'app/feeds/translations/', $new_filename
);
Use This

Comment: now syay: `fopen(C:\laragon\www\....\storage\/app\app/feeds/translations/translator_translations - 2019-04-15 06:32:09.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: i Know  your directory $file->storeAs( storage_path('app/feeds/translations/'), $new_filename ); Use this I hope Work Fine

Comment: try with this storage_path('feeds/translations/', $new_filename);